# Does a Fractions Control exist for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, user-input

I am so-so with WPF so I am unsure if I would be able to build a nice control myself but what I am searching for is a user control that lets the user enter in values in fraction-form. So if they have a value of 146.5, they would enter it as a fraction of 146 1/2. Maybe there is an easier way but I would assume the user would enter in the whole number like a normal textbox (146) and then has a slick way of just entering a fraction (if any) with it.

Does such a control exist somewhere?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: OMG! He's in the research phase of his project. His question is a valid one. Perhaps you should contribute value instead of politics. Why should he write something if it already exists?

Comment: OP just asked if a built-in WPF control that matches his requirement exists, that's just not a "please recommend best lib" question. Stop acting like brainless bots. I wish I could downvote comments.

Comment: They are bots and it's becoming really annoying that stackoverflow has devolved to this.

Comment: *Perhaps you should contribute value instead of politics*... @ScottNimrod, perhaps you should read the [relevant page from the Help Centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? We didn't write these guidelines, we just follow them as we're required to do... if you don't want to follow them, then please feel free to answer this question, although the guidelines are pretty clear on this point.

Comment: @ScottNimrod I do help if I know, not as an answer but as a comment. I do help in comments for questions which I close also. In this case, I don't know such control. I'm pretty sure there won't be something, because it is not too general.

Comment: @Sheridan You are a human and not a bot. Therefore you can use your special gift of judgement to validate a post instead of following protocol like a bot.

Comment: LOL Sorry guys. If there is a different StackOverflow meta I should post to, I will gladly do it. I wasn't sure where this would fit.

Comment: These guidelines were written for a reason and they're pretty clear on this matter: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam*. As users of this website, we're obliged to follow them (whether we agree with them or not). If you disagree with them, then feel free to leave a post on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) to try and get them changed. Until then, I'll keep following the current guidelines.

Comment: Sorry @Travyguy9, you appear to have asked a question that is off topic for Stack Overflow for the reason highlighted above. You will not have any more luck asking on Meta either. Your answer in short is no, there is no such control, but it wouldn't take you long to write one using a few `TextBox`es.

Comment: Ken2K contributed a meaningful answer based on the poster's intent. I only wish we all can learn from Ken's pragmatic interpretation of the question.

Comment: @ScottNimrod I wish you understand what are rules. What are spams etc.

Comment: @Bots I have one question. Did this post provide value for others in regards to using ValueConverters as a pattern when considering the creation of a new control? If this question and the associated answer does indeed add value to the existing repository of questions and answers, then perhaps the moderators are stifling valuable questions and answers by following static rules versus using discernment.

Comment: @ScottNimrod This is not the place to discuss these things. Here only question/answer. And probably some constructive comments. If you need to have a discussion, go ask question in [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and you may invite me by commenting here if you prefer. Our comments here just adds noise to the post as they are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built-in to do what you want. What you could do is to use a normal `TextBox` and a value converter to convert from/to fractions/doubles.

[This should help](http://andora.us/blog/2012/04/19/wpf-double-to-fraction-converter/) (of course you'll have to modify/adapt it, but it should help you starting).

Comment: A wonderful contribution to a question that involves a pattern to leverage.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I will take a stab at building a control for this.